# ReactJS Warning: Can only update a mounted or mounting component

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a multipage app with reactjs and I am successfully pulling the data and loading the components into each page, but I am unsure why my warning pops up when leaving a mounted page. (Ex: Home page -> Bitcoin, throws the error Can only update a mounted or mounting component. 
I was thinking maybe I have to unmount the component but I am loading data through a socket, not setting anything except the state. If it's the state, do I need to clear the state (if so, how)? If not, what may be causing this warning?

[image: Error I am receiving]

Here is my current code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
import NumberFormat from 'react-number-format';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

class marketdata extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      response: {},
      endpoint: "http://127.0.0.1:4001"
      };
    }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { endpoint } = this.state;
    const socket = socketIOClient(endpoint);
    socket.on("message", mi => (
      this.setState({ response: mi }))
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {

  }

  render() {

    const { response } = this.state;
    const coins = response.cc || [];

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <br></br>
          <div className="market_data">
            <h4>
                Market Cap: <NumberFormat value={response.mc} displayType={'text'} thousandSeparator={true} prefix = {'$'} /> |
                24 Hr Volume: <NumberFormat value={response.vol} displayType={'text'} thousandSeparator={true} prefix = {'$'} />
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div className="coin_container">
            <table className="table table-striped table-bordered">
              <thead className="thead-dark">
                  <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Coin</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Market Cap</th>
                    <th>Circulating Supply</th>
                    <th>Change 24Hr</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    {
                      coins.map((coin,i) => (
                        <tr key={i}>
                          <td className="coin_rank">{coin.rank}</td>
                          <td className="coin_link">
                            <img className = "coin_logo" src={require('./logos/' + coin.id + '.png')} alt = {coin.id}/>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <Link to={'/coins/' + coin.id}>{coin.name}</Link>
                          </td>
                          <td className="coin_price"><NumberFormat value={coin.price_usd} displayType={'text'} thousandSeparator={true} prefix={'$'} /></td>
                          <td className="market_cap"><NumberFormat value={coin.market_cap_usd} displayType={'text'} thousandSeparator={true} prefix={'$'} /></td>
                          <td className="coin_supply"><strong>{coin.symbol}</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;<NumberFormat value={coin.available_supply} displayType={'text'} thousandSeparator={true} /></td>
                          <td className="coin_change">{coin.percent_change_24h}%</td>
                        </tr>
                      ))
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default marketdata;
```

Comment: close the socket connection on componentUnmount, otherwise socket will try to update the state even after component got unMount and it will throw error

Comment: @abhirathore2006 oh, then would i open a new connection in a new page if I had a multi-page app?

Comment: best way is to open the socket in a component which is always mounted, such as TitleBar, Footer

Comment: @abhirathore2006 ok, so I closed the socket but the warning is still there. So, from what I am understanding is, mount socket on an always mounted component, then I transfer data within the project components, correct?

Comment: yes, that's the idea and for transfering data you can use Redux or any other similar implementation

Comment: @abhirathore2006 will this get rid of the warning message I have then? Sounds like the structure was my issue, heh (noobie learning react here)

Comment: yes, warning will go away